# How can I get my code to recognize the array number is too large before the user has to type all movie titles?

Tags: c#, arrays, menu, .net-framework-version

I have tried parsing, I have tried putting the mainmenu option there so that the menu just pops up after the error message, but I want the program to recognize when theres a typo. 
For example, max 10 entries... But the user typed 11. 
I want the program to immediately say, "You've typed too large of a number, please enter a number equal to or less than 10."

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declare Variables
        double[] showPrice;
        string[] showTitles;
        int menuChoice;
        int arrayLength;
        int i;

        //Initialize Variables
        arrayLength = 0;
        showPrice = new double[arrayLength];
        showTitles = new string[arrayLength];
        menuChoice = 0;
        i = 0;

        try
        {
            do
            {
                menuChoice = MainMenu();

                if (menuChoice == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Add Movies to Choose From");
                    Console.Write("How many movies would you like to add?(Max 10) ");
                    arrayLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    showTitles = new string[arrayLength];
                    showPrice = new double[arrayLength];

                    for (i = 0; i < showTitles.Length; i++)
                    {
                        showTitles[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    if (i > 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OOPS, you have entered " + i + ". Please enter number 10 or less.");
                        arrayLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Isn't it as simple as `if (arrayLength > 10)`  ?

Comment: No unfortunately it still requires the user to enter all titles first :(

Comment: Did you put the `if` statement before the part of the code where the user enters the titles?

Comment: its a little better... how can I get the code to go back to the question? "How many movie titles... " so that they enter an accurate number? Sorry, I have been struggling with this assignment for a few days now :(

Comment: If you want to repeat a section of code until a condition is met, use a [`while`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) loop.

Comment: how can i eliminate the entries? It is still coming up so they have to enter all 11 titles.

Comment: I think your code need to repeat the while loop until the user has entered a value that it can use, i.e. a value that is 10 or less.